# Can I install Sierra on a Mac Mini 2007 (MB138LL/A)?

Tags: macos, mac-mini

I have an old Mac mini and I'm deciding on whether to get rid of it or to try to install the newest OS to use voice recognition. Does anybody have first-hand experience?

If i upgrade the specs, would this the new os work, or is the 1.83 GHz core and integrated graphics card too slow?

Comment: Have a look at "Mac Hardware Requirements" in [MacOS Sierra - Technical Specifications](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP742).

Comment: Whats with the downvotes? I just wanted to double check.

Comment: while I didn't down vote, it's evident that you are getting down voted for any/all of 3 reasons:  1)  info on widely available in multiple sources, 2)this (similar) question has been asked many times here; which both of those leads to 3) you obviously didn't do any research.  I highly suggest you take the [Tour](http://apple.stackexchange.com/tour)

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid that machine is long out of support. the last OS it's capable of running is Lion, 10.7.5

Ref: [EveryMac](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/mac_mini/specs/mac-mini-core-2-duo-1.83-specs.html)